# How to update value and label in attribute REST API Magento2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have an attribute manufacturers, it has a value, I want to select them and change which I need using Rest API

I tried sending a request like this

> http://magengree/rest/V1/products/attributes/manufacturer/1/options

i got this Response

```
Response {
    "message": "Request does not match any route."
}
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing wrong URL. Please see the details below.

Get all available options for product attribute

> Request Method : **GET**
>
> Request Link Syntax :
>   `<base_url>/rest/V1/products/attributes/<attribute_code>/options`
>
> Request Link in your case :
>   http://magengree/rest/V1/products/attributes/manufacturer/options

Add new option for product attribute

> Request Method : **POST**
>
> Request Link Syntax :
>   `<base_url>/rest/V1/products/attributes/<attribute_code>/options`
>
> Request Link in your case :
>   http://magengree/rest/V1/products/attributes/manufacturer/options
>
> Request Body : JSON(application/json)
>
> ```
> {
>   "option": 
>         {
>               "label": "Apple",
>               "value": "214",
>               "sort_order": 0,
>               "is_default": true,
>               "store_labels": [
>               {
>                   "store_id": 0,
>                   "label": "Apple3"
>               }
>               ]
>         }
> }
> ```

Delete any existing option for product attribute

> Request Method : **DELETE**
>
> Request Link Syntax :
>   `<base_url>/rest/V1/products/attributes/<attribute_code>/options/<option_id>`
>
> Request Link in your case :
>   http://magengree/rest/V1/products/attributes/manufacturer/options/214

Make sure you add `Authorization` token for all request.

For more information Refer `catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1` from https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

Hope it finds you helpful.

Comment: This will add a new option in that attribute, not update existing options!!